# How to set the doctype for all skin layouts at once?

Tags: doctype, skin, dotnetnuke-7

I'm trying to set the doctype for my Skin to the html5 `<!doctype html>` doctype. However, I want to prevent the need to have to remember to do this for each variant I create. That is, my current structure was:

```
_default\Skins\MySkin\TwoColumnLayout.ascx
_default\Skins\MySkin\TwoColumnLayout.doctype.ascx
```

With the latter containing the contents:

```xml
<SkinDocType><![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE html>]]></SkinDocType>
```

Now I want to create more `ascx` layouts, without having to remember to create a doctype file. So I followed DNN instructions I found [here](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/134867/using-skin-level-doctypes) and [here](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/doctype), creating this structure:

```
_default\Skins\MySkin\TwoColumnLayout.ascx
_default\Skins\MySkin\ThreeColumnLayout.ascx
_default\Skins\MySkin\Default.doctype.ascx (A)
_default\Skins\MySkin\MySkin.doctype.ascx (B)
_default\Skins\MySkin\MySkindoctype.ascx (C)
```

But none of them worked. I had (A) there as my gut-feeling attempt, option (B) from my first time reading the first bit of linked documentation, and (C) from the second time reading the documentation. However, none of them worked...

Of course I can repeat the doctype file for each view, but I'm bound to forget that one day. Is there a way to set the doctype *once* for all views in my skin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a "fallback" doctype which will be used if none is specified. You can find this setting at:

> Host Settings > Basic Settings tab > Appearance header > "Fallback Skin Doctype" (last setting)

Set it to something you want as a default, e.g.:

[image: setting screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Even though it's not really a default at the *skin* level (is it?) as I (thought I) needed, it would work for my situation nonetheless as all my portals will have this same skin. Will try your suggestion tomorrow.